# how to replace only one key/value pair by using jq in json file?

Tags: json, jq

My json template is as of this:

```
{ 
  "interface_settings": [
    {
      "name": "lan", 
      "status": "$status", 
      ...
    },
    {
     "name": "lte1",
     "status": "$status", 
     ...
    },
    { 
      ...
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

And my jq command:

```
jq '.interface_settings[].status="up"' <my_json_template file>
```

will update both status values within the interface_settings section. How may I just have one changed ?

Comment: What criterion is to be used to determine which one?

Comment: let's say I want to update the status where the name is "lan", how this command would be look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let's say I want to update the status where the name is "lan"

One way to update all such objects would be:

```
.interface_settings |= map( if .name == "lan" then .status = "up" else . end)
```

### Just the first such

```
.interface_settings |= (reduce .[] as $x (null;
  if .done
  then .ans += [$x]
  elif $x.name == "lan"
  then .ans += [$x | .status = "up"] | .done = true
  else .ans += [$x]
  end) | .ans)
```

Comment: First or second solution?

Comment: I was using the 1st solution. I am still try to understand the 2nd one.

Comment: I have just tried the 2nd option, and it works for me too. But 2nd option is too fancy for me to understand what is going on, I guess.